# Crash Tesseract Package in R

Tags: r, tesseract

I am using R in RStudio and want to use the tesseract package. Whenever I run the command:

```
library(tesseract)
```

RStudio gets a fatal error and immediately crashes and terminated the session. This also happens when I reference the package with “::”. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling tesseract as well as restarting my computer. I am using R 4.2.1.

Comment: R 4.2.1 hasn't been released.  Does this happen if you run R outside of RStudio?

Comment: Sorry - I meant 4.2.0.

And yes - it crashes base R as well.

Comment: With no more responses here, I think you'll have to post an issue on https://github.com/ropensci/tesseract/issues .  You should include the result of `sessionInfo()` and anything else they ask you for.